# Formulation of a set-theory problem.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here the problem 1.31(a) from Sohrab, Basic Real Analysis

### Problem

- (a) Show that a set $S$ is finite if and only if each non-empty subset of $\mathcal{P}(S)$ (partially ordered by inclusion) has a minimal element.

I cite also part (b), perhaps it can help:

- (b) Show that a set $S$ is infinite if and only if $S$ is equivalent to some proper subset of itself. \textit{Hint}: Recall that any infinite set contains a countably infinite subset.

### Question

How to understand the problem above (part a)?

Consider $S=\{a,b,c\}$, $\mathcal{S}=\{\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\}\}\subset\mathcal{P}(S)$. $S$ is finite, but $\mathcal{S}$ has no minimal element.
This example contradicts the claim of the problem? I should miss somenthing.

Comment: **Every** element of $\mathcal{S}$ is minimal. A set $S$ is minimal in $\mathcal{S}$ if there is no $S'\in\mathcal{S}$ such that $S'\subsetneqq S$.

Comment: I understand now, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: If $S$ is infinite, it has a countably infinite subset $C=\{s_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let

$$T_n=\{s_k:k\ge n\}\;,$$

and show that $\{T_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ has no minimal element.

Conversely, if $\mathscr{A}\subseteq\wp(S)$ has no minimal element, show that there is a sequence $\langle A_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ in $\mathscr{A}$ such that

$$A_0\supsetneqq A_1\supsetneqq A_2\supsetneqq\ldots\;,$$

and use this sequence to find a countably infinite subset of $S$.

Comment: Thank you, I enjoy your hint.

Comment: @LiPo: You’re welcome.